# Use potential method to find amortized running time?

Tags: algorithm

So here is a challenge that I was faced with (from introduction to algorithms 3rd edition):

> Suppose we perform a sequence of *n* operations on a data structure in
>   which the *i*th operation costs *i* if i is an exact power of 2, and 1
>   otherwise. Use the potential method to determine the amortized cost
>   per operation.

I thought that I understood the potential method until I encountered this; I have tried and tried to solve it but cannot. My struggle is when I have to define the potential $\phi(D_i)$ (the potential of data structure $D$ after the *i*th operation).

My basic idea was to define the potential function such that $\phi(D_i) = i$ when *i* is a factor of two. This way I would be able to "pay" for the cost of this operation and don't even have to analyze the case when *i* is a factor of 2 any further.

However, this may or may not be the correct idea - please don't let it hinder your creativity/tell me if it is wrong and what would be the correct thing to do :) Can any of you clever wizards take me through the steps to solve this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your actual costs look like this:

```
1 2 1 4 1 1 1 8 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 16 ...
```

What you want to do is pay for future operations now to smooth out the spikes.  If we spread out each spike over the elements between the previous spike and it we get this:

```
1 2 5/2 5/2 11/4 11/4 11/4 11/4 23/8 23/8 23/8 ....
```

This is still complicated.  But we want an upper bound so it is OK to *overpay* to get something simple.  So for the interval `(2^n - 2^(n+1)]` (not including first, including the last) there are `2^n` numbers.  We have `1` for most of the elements, and then we have to spread out payment for a `2^(n+1)` spike.  So we cover it if we pay `1` for each element and `2` for the future spike.  This leads to the following payments:

```
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3....
```

Is your analysis now easier?

The moral of the story.  Smooth out the spikes and prefer simplicity over accuracy.  This will make your analysis easier.

Comment: Gosh, thank you so much. I have asked this question twice on the math forum without an answer.

Comment: Oh, and just to be sure: How exactly would you then define the potential function from the preliminary logic you went through? Like if you should write the potential function as a pure function of some variable(s)

Comment: @Dip The CS forum might have been better.  I would define the potential function as `3` after I figured out what would work.   But the principle is what I described.

Comment: But then the potential of the data structure would never increase but always be a constant. Isn't the point that the potential increases with the number of operations such that at some point the potential is enough "credit" to pay for certain types of operations?

Comment: @Dip Sorry, double checking the definition, the total potential should be `3n`.  So the payment each time is `3`.  And yes, you are accounting now for work you may have to do in the future, so that by the time you actually do that work, it is already covered.